# Don't auto-delete questions from deleted users if there are positive score answers

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, deleted-accounts

Recently, when a user deleted his account on Lifehacks, his questions with negative scores and no accepted answers were deleted, including [this feature request](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1151/59). However, some users [thought that this question was useful, and started a (successful) motion to undelete it](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1257/59).

I don't think it should have been deleted -- yes, the question had a negative score, no there wasn't an accepted answer....but there was an answer with a positive score. Why should positive score answers be deleted, ever?

**In short:**

> **Please protect positive score answers to deleted users' negative score questions from damaging deletion by the Roomba.**

Comment: Because upvotes are really easy to get nowadays?

Comment: Not only that, but IMO a deleted user's *meta* posts should not be automatically deleted.  Sometimes it's valuable to have a record for "considered and rejected" to point to.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Good point.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't understand what you're saying.